# Toolbar with ViewPager not restoring last tab selected when starting new activity

Tags: android, tabs, android-toolbar

I'm using the v7 widget Toolbar and setting it as my support action bar in my AppCompatAcivity.  When I'm on a different tab and start a new activity, I can't restore the last tab I was on with `onSaveInstanceState`.  `onCreate`'s savedInstanceState would be null and `onRestoreInstanceState` is never called when coming from activity 2 to my activity with tabs. How can I solve this?

```
public class ContactsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static String TAB_POSITION = "POSITION";

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.logo_spokeo);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new RecentContactsFragment(), "Recent Contacts");
        adapter.addFragment(new AddressBookFragment(), "Address Book");
        adapter.addFragment(new RecentContactsFragment(), "Settings");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(savedInstanceState.getInt(TAB_POSITION, 0), false);
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putInt(TAB_POSITION, tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition());
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(savedInstanceState.getInt(TAB_POSITION), true);
    }
}
```